# Getting the data in the chrome intent

Tags: android, google-chrome

I've made and app that should be able to get images shared from other app. I can get stuff from gallery and filemanagers. But I'm not able to get it from chrome. When I get the resource uri it is something like that:

content://com.android.chrome.FileProvider/images/screenshot/14570916360611558676392.jpg

I've tried to resolve it with cursors but without any success. Is there someway to recover the resource?

Answer (score 0):

The only way works for me is to call `ContentResolver.openInputStream(uri)` to get a `FileInputStream` from the original image. With that, you can create a copy of the image and use it.